# Как правильно получить дату отняв от текущей N-месяцев\лет\дней в PHP?

Tags: php, дата, datetime

Есть текущая дата, которая определяется при помощи `date();` и есть функция которая принимает в себя переменную `$date="";` которая передается в форматах: 1 (любое число это минус `n` лет с текущего момента), 3m (минус 3 месяца с текущего момента), 26d (минус 26 дней с текущего момента). Как мне правильно отминусовать эти числа чтобы на выходе получить корректную дату? Читал статьи что можно перевести даты в число потом минуснуть или сплюсовать их, а потом результат перевести обратно. Может есть что-то уже написанное, вопрос явно подымался не один раз.

Comment: явно. а это значит что по запросу отнять дату РНР будет примерно миллион готовых ответов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может проще так?
`$n = 2;`
`date("d.m.Y",strtotime("-$n year -3 month -26 days"));`